# stochastic ordering and convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume we have two sequences of rv. defined on the same probability space $\{X_{n}\}$ and $\{Y_{n}\}$ such that 
$$
X_{n} \stackrel{d}{\to} X
$$

$$
Y_{n} \stackrel{d}{\to} Y
$$
and $X\geq_{s}Y$, where $\geq_{s}$ means stochastically greater.

Is this true then $P[X_{n} \geq Y_{n}] \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: You will do better here if you show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

No: Just consider constant variables, with $X_n = 0$ (so $X = 0$) and $Y_n = n^{-1}$ (so $Y = 0$). But maybe you were meaning strict inequalities somewhere…?